# How do you read the source code of a Python module?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import, python-module

I'm trying to understand how some built-in Python modules work under the hood.

For example, with the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Where is the definition of the function `Tk`?

I've been searching through the [tkinter source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/tkinter) but cannot find it.
The code several time calls `import Tkinter` which is also strange because this *is* `Tkinter`, so why is it importing itself?

Hope someone can help resolve my confusion

Comment: [It helps to realize that thing is a class, not a function.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1996) Also, https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class Tk` is in:

- Py 2.7: [`Tkinter.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py#L1795)
- Py 3.6: [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1996).

In general, when you `import Foo`, if `Foo` is a module implemented using Python code, and there is a `Foo/__init__.py` in Python's [search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), that file runs.  [Some more information here,](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html) plus official docs on modules for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).  That may not be the case for modules built in to the Python interpreter, such as 2.7's `Tkinter`.

#### `Tkinter` specifics

- In Python 2, `Tkinter` is a Python module and `tkinter` (lowercase) is a C module that `Tkinter` uses ([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#how-tk-and-tkinter-are-related)).
- In Python 3, `tkinter` (lowercase) is a Python module and `_tkinter` (with underscore) is the C module that `tkinter` uses ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#how-tk-and-tkinter-are-related)).

Comment: in python2.7, Tk is _not_ in `__init__.py`.  It's in Tkinter.py. I think it's only in `__init__.py` in python 3. In this case we know the OP is using python2 because they are using `Tkinter` rather than `tkinter`.

Answer (score 6):

Although cxw's answer is accurate and correct, I would suggest installing IPython, if you find yourself looking through the code of Python modules often. It's a better version of the python console:

```
$ pip install IPython
...
$ ipython
```

Then, to see the code of a class / function / module, type its name in and add `??`:

```
from Tkinter import *
Tk??
```